# Sentence Transformation: ... enough ... to ..... so ... that

Tags: difference

> Tu Pee was hungry enough to eat a horse.
>   Tu Pee was so hungry that he could eat a horse.

I'd like to know whether the two sentences are exactly the same. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The second sentence talks about Tu Pee's *extended* capacity to eat something as big as a horse. The reason is Tu Pee's isn't hungry, he is *famished*.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a common idiom, I don't think anybody would have trouble recognizing them as the same thing. They both mean "Tu Pee was very hungry".

I may be wrong, but I can't see any difference in the literal interpretations either. In either case, we're saying Tu Pee's great hunger enables him to "eat a horse".

However, I could imagine scenarios where they are different.

> Tu Pee was hungry enough that he ate a horse.
>   Tu Pee was so hungry that he ate a horse.

"Hungry enough" says he *could* eat a horse, as in your first example. But I don't think my first example sounds very natural. My second example sounds much better to me.

I can't think of an example where this would make sense, but there is a way to interpret your second example differently.

> Tu Pee was happy enough to eat a horse.
>   Tu Pee was so happy that he could eat a horse.

The new metaphor makes little sense, but the literal meaning of the first example means his great happiness enables him to eat a horse. The second example could easily mean the same thing. But it could also mean Tu Pee is capable of eating a horse, and that capacity makes him happy.

> Tu Pee was so happy because he knew he could eat a horse.

So applying the same grammar to your second example, we could interpret it as being hungry because of his capacity to eat a horse.

> Thinking about his ability to eat a horse caused Tu Pee's stomach to rumble with hunger.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any significant difference in meaning between these sentences.  Both the sentences are indicative that Tu Pee, because of its hunger, was able to eat a horse.

The only subtle diffetence in meaning is that the phrase 'enough hungry' indicates that Tu Pee was as hungry as is necessary to eat a horse. On the other hand, the phrase 'so hungry' means that Tu Pee was very hungry or hungry to such a great extent that it could eat a horse.

In other words, Tu Pee's hunger shown in the latter sentence is more intense than that in the former.

Answer (score 0):

I see no appreciable difference in their ultimate meaning. With  **could {verb}**  capacity-to-do is *explicit*.  With **to {verb}**, capacity-to-do is *implicit* in the pattern.

> hungry enough to eat...
>
> so hungry (that) he could eat...

The word "that" is in parentheses to show it's optional.

The complement to the "{modifier} enough" pattern is usually a *to*-infinitive phrase (*to eat*) but some speakers will supply a *that*-clause there (*that he could eat*).

The complement to the "so {modifier}" pattern  is a *that*-clause or a reduced clause (but not a *to*-infinitive phrase).

Whether it is a *to*-infinitive phrase or a *that*-clause, the pattern indicates a sufficient degree of the property expressed by {modifier} to do the thing expressed by the verb-phrase in the complement.

**He was so tall that he could dunk the basketball without leaping.

He was tall enough to dunk the basketball without leaping.**